# R: Count number of days before specific date by ID

Tags: r, date, intervals

I have data frame with multiple columns, most importantly id and date. I would like to make another column in R which will fill in every row which day of date interval is by id.
Something like this.

```
id  date 
1   12/31/2019
1   12/30/2019
2   12/26/2019
2   12/25/2019
2   12/24/2019
3   12/22/2019
3   12/21/2019
3   12/20/2019
3   12/19/2019
4   12/15/2019
4   12/14/2019
4   12/13/2019
```

to make like this

```
id  date        date count
1   12/31/2019  2
1   12/30/2019  1
2   12/26/2019  3
2   12/25/2019  2
2   12/24/2019  1
3   12/22/2019  4
3   12/21/2019  3
3   12/20/2019  2
3   12/19/2019  1
4   12/15/2019  3
4   12/14/2019  2
4   12/13/2019  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(date_count = dense_rank(as.Date(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")))

      id date       date_count
   <int> <chr>           <int>
 1     1 12/31/2019          2
 2     1 12/30/2019          1
 3     2 12/26/2019          3
 4     2 12/25/2019          2
 5     2 12/24/2019          1
 6     3 12/22/2019          4
 7     3 12/21/2019          3
 8     3 12/20/2019          2
 9     3 12/19/2019          1
10     4 12/15/2019          3
11     4 12/14/2019          2
12     4 12/13/2019          1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, date_count := frank(as.IDate(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"), 
              ties.method = 'dense'), id][]
#    id       date date_count
# 1:  1 12/31/2019          2
# 2:  1 12/30/2019          1
# 3:  2 12/26/2019          3
# 4:  2 12/25/2019          2
# 5:  2 12/24/2019          1
# 6:  3 12/22/2019          4
# 7:  3 12/21/2019          3
# 8:  3 12/20/2019          2
# 9:  3 12/19/2019          1
#10:  4 12/15/2019          3
#11:  4 12/14/2019          2
#12:  4 12/13/2019          1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L), date = c("12/31/2019", "12/30/2019", "12/26/2019", "12/25/2019", 
"12/24/2019", "12/22/2019", "12/21/2019", "12/20/2019", "12/19/2019", 
"12/15/2019", "12/14/2019", "12/13/2019")),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `data.table` option:

```
DT[order(id, as.IDate(date, format="%m/%d/%Y")), dc := rowid(id)]
```